# cakephp getLastInsertID / Model->id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is  getLastInsertID and Model->id  same? And which one can happen concurrency problem ?

```
$this->Model->save($this->data);
__thisFunctionTakesAVeryLongTimeToExecute(); //function 1
$insertId = $this->Model->getLastInsertId();
```

Does getLastInsertId() return the ID from the data I've saved 2 lines above. Or does it return the latest ID that's created?

I mean
what happen if when the function 1 (__thisFunctionTakesAVeryLongTimeToExecute();) execute another user do an another save. then which id will i get?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->Model->id
```

Is used to set an id and read or modify data related.

```
$this->Model->getLastInsertID();
```

Return the id of the last inserted row in this model.

For your last question, make a test ! And publish your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I have another similar problem.
If I put

```
 $oid  = $this->Home->Order->getLastInsertID();
 $order = $this->Home->Order->find('first',array('conditions'=>array( 'Order.id'=>$oid)));
```

the model associations between Order and its hasMany tables are destroyed.

If I put

```
 $oid  = 1; // for example
 $order = $this->Home->Order->find('first',array('conditions'=>array( 'Order.id'=>$oid)));
```

the model associations are maintained!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Use below code for cakePHP 3.0  or above

```
 $result = $this->ModelName->save($data)
 echo $result->id;
```